# Warum haben deutsche Witze das Verb am Anfang?

Tags: verb, joke, sentence-structure

Witze haben im Deutschen häufig eine Verb-initial-Wortstellung (der Linguist sagt auch *V1*):

> Kommt ein Betrunkener zum Photographen und lallt: „Bitte machen Sie ein Gruppenfoto von mir!“ – Sagt der Photograph: „Gut, stellen Sie sich bitte im Halbkreis auf!“

V1 ist eigentlich ziemlich ungewöhnlich im Deutschen und kommt weder in normalen Haupt- noch Nebensätzen vor, nur in Frage- und Aufforderungssätzen und allenfalls noch in eher seltenen Konjunktivkonstruktionen („Hätten wir doch gestern Lotto gespielt!“)

Woran liegt es, dass gerade bei Witzen ganz normale Hauptsätze auf einmal verbinitial sind?